# Modificar URL para requisições REST

Tags: delphi, web-service, rest, delphi-xe8, datasnap

Tenho um serviço rodando em Delphi em `DataSnap REST`, para acessar qualquer função do `REST` via link seria assim:

```
servidor:porta/datasnap/rest/classmethods/funcao/parametros
```

eu precisava alterar a url de

```
/datasnap/rest/classmethods/
```

para uma outra URL,
estive dando uma olhada que poderia alterar nas propriedades `DSContext, RESTContext e PathInfo` do componente `DSHTTPWebDispatcher1`,  para eu fazer isso teria que alterar até o classmetodos, não queria alterar essa parte.

Queria saber se tem um jeito para alterar a URL do `Datasnap REST` para acesso, além desse que eu mencionei.

Comment: Tb gostaria de fazer estas modificações. Como usuou a função criada para corrigir o problema com o contest?

Comment: @RichardSlater, conseguiu resolver o problema?... eu respondi a minha pergunta logo abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma, criei um projeto `DataSnap Server`, na classe `ServerContainerUnit` que o próprio projeto cria, tem um componente onde ele fica encarregado de fazer a comunicação via `Http`, que seria o `HttpService`, nesse componente tem a propriedade `DSContext` e `RESTContext` a onde consegui alterar, mas mesmo alterando dessa forma, meu problema não foi resolvido, então tive que alterar na classe `ServerMethodUnit` e criar uma função para resolver.